# Можно ли построить OLAP кубы из бд типа OLTP без преобразования в DWH?

Tags: sql, база-данных, olap, хранилище

Всем привет
Можно ли построить OLAP кубы из бд типа OLTP без преобразования в DWH? 
Если да, то есть какая то статистика по скорости?

По всей информации в интернете OLAP кубы создаются только на основе DWH(Data Warehouse).
То есть нужно обычное нормализованную бд типа OLTP превратить в DWH, а потом на основании DWH строить OLAP кубы.

БД: PostgreSQL

Comment: почитайте про ROLAP

Comment: Привидите, пожалуйста короткий пример того, что вы строите.

Comment: Кубы на то они и кубы, что в них данные заранее агрегированы. Данные извлечены из OLTP-хранилища, как-то обработаны и приведены в вид, удобный для аналитики. После чего аналитические запросы выполняются быстро.

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? Например, в Sql Server есть Columnstore. И можно [одновременно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#can-i-combine-rowstore-and-columnstore-on-the-same-table) использовать поколоночное и построчное хранение.

Comment: @0xdb Ответил выше

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ответил выше